# SQL statement in ms access db bringing up InputBox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have VBA for a form.

I'm trying to take the information in a textbox on the form and update a particular field in a table. (haven't figured out how to do that properly)
This line of code is my current try but I'm getting unexpected behavior

The program doesn't continue executing after this

```
   If (Not IsNull([New_Value_Box].Value)) Then
       DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [Export_NDC_Certification] Set " & [Field_List].Value & " = " & [New_Value_Box].Value & " WHERE SellerLoanIdentifier = " & Current_Loan
    End If
```

it does however open an input box with the value of Current_Loan as the caption. It doesn't appear to do anything with the input and it doesn't execute any further code. I've used MsgBox's for debugging and its definitely coming from this line. This line was what I came across for taking a value and updating a particular table value with it. if this isn't the way to do it any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Examine the `UPDATE` statement you're asking Access to execute.  Use `Debug.Print` to print it to the Immediate window.  Then Ctrl+g will take you there.  If you can't spot the problem with the statement, copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: My guess is the following piece may be a problem, but may not be the only problem: `Set " & [Field_List].Value & " = "`

Comment: Thank you Hansup. it was totally the field list value I was passing. they didn't correlate properly with the values in the corresponding table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend using the `Execute` method (of either [DAO.Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx) or [DAO.QueryDef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821728.aspx)), instead of using `DoCmd.RunSQL`. This makes debugging a lot easier ([here's a forum post](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1654908&view=findpost&p=1654938) with more information).

Also, since it seems that you need values in all your controls (`[Field_List]`, `[New_Value_Box]`, and `Current_Loan`), you should do a null check on all of those.

As noted by @HansUp, your actual SQL string is likely causing the issue, so you probably want to store that in a separate variable you can then output to the immediate window.

With all that being said, revised code might look something like this:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String

If _
        IsNull([New_Value_Box].value) Or _
        IsNull([Field_List].value) Or _
        IsNull([Current_Loan].value) _
Then
    ' handle missing input
Else
    ' we know all required fields have values, so can proceed
    strSQL = _
            "UPDATE [Export_NDC_Certification " & _
            "SET " & [Field_List].value & "=" & [New_Value_Box].value & " " & _
            "WHERE SellerLoanIdentifier=" & Current_Loan

    Debug.Print strSQL

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdf.SQL = strSQL
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
End If


' clean up DAO objects
Set qdf = Nothing: Set qdf = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: My answer was a lot like this, except i was using parameters, till i realized that Field_List is a value in a control.

Comment: Yeah, a parameterized query was my first thought too.

Comment: My WAG is that `Set " & [Field_List].Value & " = "` yields `Set Current_Loan = ` and that field does not exist in the table ... hence the "missing parameter" symptom.

Comment: Had to look up what **WAG** stood for... :)

Comment: lol I didn't see these updates before I answered. this is great advice I'll see about incorporating the DAO.database stuff. yeah there is input filtering and error checking for what the fields hold earlier in the code. my problem was the [Field_List].value 's didn't correlate to the table values properly. and I wasn't encapsulating the terms in the SQL statement with proper quotes.